# How to turn on Autocomplete commands in texshop

Tags: editors, mac, texshop, auto-completion

I'm a newbie to texshop and I cant get autocomplete to work. A quick search on it tells me to do something with ~/library/Texshop/Keyboard/autocompletion. Plist file but I'm stumped. Texshop version  4.27(4.27)

Comment: Autocompletion should be on by default I think. Check in the Source pane of the TeXShop preferences which key activates it (either Esc or Tab).

Comment: AutoComplete is an old name for what is now known as Key Bindings. There is also Command Completion which may be what you want. Take a look at the `Help->TeXShop Tips and Tricks` document for a bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here after command completing stopped working (long time TexShop user).

1. The format seems to have changed and older command completion lists may not work without modification
2. Try starting fresh.  Quit TexShop. Move your old folder ~/Library/TeXShop/CommandCompletion to the desktop.  Restart TexShop.  This will create a clean, and current, version with a nice QuickStart guide and documentation at that new location.

Good Luck!